# Java regex issue (negative lookahead & lookbehind)

Tags: java, regex, kotlin, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I need your help guys!! This is a tricky java regex issue, been search for a solution for a couple hours... Here it is:

In the following text, I want to match the "boat" word...

1. and include "bunch of " if place just before it.
2. and include " propeller" if place just after it.
3. or don't match if preceeded by "for a " even with "bunch of " in between.
4. or don't match if followed by " trailer" even with "propeller " in between.

> *I have a boat to sell. It comes with extra boat propellers but does not come with a boat trailer (the boat is pretty big so you might need a boat propeller trailer too). I used to have a bunch of boats but my passion for a boat faded with time. I did not think people would have interest for a bunch of boats but this is my last one, so Yeéé! :)*

### The following parts should match:

- ***boat***                   ("boat")
- ***bunch of boats***         ("boat" preceeded by "bunch of ")
- ***boat propeller***         ("boat followed by " propeller")

### The following parts should NOT match (not even partially):

- ***for a boat***             ("boat" preceeded by "for a ")
- ***boat trailer***           ("boat followed by " trailer")
- ***for a bunch of boats***   ("boat" preceeded by "bunch of " which is preceeded by "for a ")
- ***boat propeller trailer*** ("boat" followed by " propeller" which is followed by " trailer")

I got this example setup in regex 101 ( https://regex101.com/r/o6S4SP/22 ) but it's not working properly :-(

PS: I'm using Regex101 for the example but "(SKIP)(FAIL)" is not supported in Java's regex syntax.

Hope anyone could help :-)

Comment: There is no need for SKIP-FAIL if you have access to code. Are you extracting or replacing?

Comment: The solution is to use a regex like `(\bfor\s+a\s+)?(?:\bbunch\s+of\s+)?\bboats?\b(?:\s+propellers?)?+(?!\s+trailers?\b)`, check if Group 1 matched and omit the match if it did. Else, use the match, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RalQPX/1). All matches with green highlight on the left will be discarded in the code. The code will differ depending on whether you extract or replace.

Comment: I'm replacing the matches by "<b>$1</b>"; the point is to highlight those words. Since I do a regex.replace, I can't add a conditional validation... There is like 5 parts to the regex a visualise and every one of them may contain a lot of possible words...

Comment: Ok, you may "abuse" the constrained width lookbehind, it will allow you to check a certain amount of spaces. Say, if there cannot be more than 100 spaces between `for a` and `boat`, use `replaceAll("(?<!\\bfor\\s{1,100}a\\s{1,100})(?:\\bbunch\\s+of\\s+)?\\bboats?\\b(?:\\s+propellers?)?+(?!\\s+trailers?\\b)", "<b>$0</b>")`. See the [Java regex demo](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyddpd4yr) (click Java button there)

Comment: Or, if the spaces are never messed up, use `replaceAll("(?<!\\bfor\\sa\\s)(?:\\bbunch\\s+of\\s+)?\\bboats?\\b(?:\\s+propellers?)?+(?!\\s+trailers?\\b)", "<b>$0</b>")`

Comment: Oh seems promising! :-) Although there's one issue around the part "interest for a bunch of <b>boats</b> but"...  This "boats" should not be replaced (Rule #3) because it's preceeded by a "for a " (before the "bunch of ") ... got an idea to fix this?

Comment: Then you have to use two lookbehinds or one with a limiting quantifier: `replaceAll("(?<!\\bfor\\sa\\s)(?<!\\bfor\\sa\\sbunch\\sof\\s)(?:\\bbunch\\s+of\\s+)?\\bboats?\\b(?:\\s+propellers?)?+(?!\\s+trailers?\\b)", "<b>$0</b>")`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ocj8rp/1)

Comment: Covering many possible combinaisons would create a huge amount of negative lookbehinds (ie: "for a bunch of", "with a set of", "containing many", "including multiple", and so on...). So, that would be a last resort solution... Could you tell me more about your "one with a limiting quantifier" part? I thought there wasn't a way to use content with variable length inside negative lookbehinds...

Comment: I already mentioned that Java's lookbehind is *constrained width*, it supports limiting quantifiers. I  meant [this](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyddpd4yr).

Comment: Oh! Awesome, did'nt catch that part the first time you mentionned it! lol

Comment: Ok, let me post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex in Java that features a *constrained-width* lookbehind pattern (supporting limiting quantifiers):

```
(?<!\bfor\sa\s(?:bunch\sof\s){0,1})(?:\bbunch\s+of\s+)?\bboats?\b(?:\s+propellers?)?+(?!\s+trailers?\b)
```

See the [**Java regex demo online (proof)**](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyEwsSBlJlY2lwZRiAgIDC0ISECgw/index.html).

In Java,

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?<!\\bfor\\sa\\s(?:bunch\\sof\\s){0,1})(?:\\bbunch\\s+of\\s+)?\\bboats?\\b(?:\\s+propellers?)?+(?!\\s+trailers?\\b)", "<b>$0</b>");
```

**Regex details**

- `(?<!\bfor\sa\s(?:bunch\sof\s){0,1})` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is

  - `\bfor\sa\s` - `for`, whitespace, `a`, whitespace
  - `(?:bunch\sof\s){0,1}` - 0 or 1 occurrences (i.e. an optional occurrence) of `bunch`, whitespace, `of`, whitespace
- `(?:\bbunch\s+of\s+)?` - an optional occurrence of `bunch`, 1+ whitespaces, `of`, 1+ whitespaces
- `\bboats?\b` - a whole word `boat` or `boats`
- `(?:\s+propellers?)?+` - an optional occurrence of 1+ whitespaces followed with `propeller` or `propellers`. **NOTE**: the `?+` possessive quantifier is key here to make the next lookahead only execute after this group pattern.
- `(?!\s+trailers?\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is 1+ whitespaces, and then `trailer` or `trailers` as a whole word.

Comment: Thanx! I should work now! Shame there no way to prevent having 2x the same sub list (ie: "bunch of")... :-)

Comment: @IceMatter I added the explanations. Yeah, with lookbehinds, it is not always that easy. If you could use optional capturing groups, it would be "simpler" and "shorter", but would involve a bit more code.